# I need to add -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON to cmake permanently

Tags: cmake, llvm

I use llvm for a few projects and I'd like to add this command line argument along with the path to llvm to my cmake permanently so I don't have to keep using it every time I run cmake.
I'd also prefer that cmake doesn't break when using it for projects which don't involve llvm.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it to `CMakeLists.txt` directly. Simply add somewhere near the top of the project:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

Not quite what you had in mind, but other than writing a script to run the command with flags, i don't think it's possible.

Comment: Are you sure this is a supported syntax?
Rather than just `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)`.
(https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html)

Comment: @valiano you are right. was still waking up when I answered. thanks.